# Repeat a Table in SSRS for each value in a Parameter (SSRS 2008 R2 - Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a query that has multiple "Practice Groups".  I want to make a report where a table repeats on a new page for each Practice Group that exists in the query.  Is this possible to so with a Parameter?

My query is as follows...

```
SELECT  arcsb_matter.matter_id as 'Matter ID',
        isnull(c.clname1,'') + ' ' + isnull(c.clname2,'') as 'Client Name',
        isnull(desc1,'') + isnull(desc2,'') as 'Matter Name',
        tk.tklast as 'Timekeeper',
        trust_amount as 'Trust',
        last_pay_amount as 'A/R Total',
        ar_unapplied as 'UNA',
        practice_group as 'Practice Group'
 FROM ((arcsb_matter
 LEFT OUTER JOIN arcsb_client ON (arcsb_client.client_id = arcsb_matter.client_id )) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN arcsb_matter_currency ON (arcsb_matter_currency.client_id = arcsb_matter.client_id AND arcsb_matter_currency.matter_id = arcsb_matter.matter_id AND (arcsb_matter_currency.currency_code = N'USD') )) 
 INNER JOIN son_db.dbo.client c on left(arcsb_matter.matter_id,6) = c.clnum 
 INNER JOIN son_db.dbo.timekeep tk on arcsb_matter.bill_timekeeper = tk.tkinit 
 WHERE  trust_amount <> 0
```

My results are as follows...  (sorry, have to hide some important data)

[image]

I would like to display these results sorted by "Trust", but a new table / new page for each "Practice Group".  I have scoured the internet profusely and can't locate a solid / detailed answer for this.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by inserting a tablix to your report, and group that tablix on `Practice Group`. Then on the properties section of the tablix you can tell SSRS to add a page break between each instance of the group, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx).